# Force type on IntelliSense autocompletion in XAML Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, intellisense

I am working on some fairly large WPF project with a ton of classes and XAML design files.

But one thing is driving me nuts: The IntelliSense Binding autocompletion sometimes does not display the correct values (mostly on situations where i cannot provide the proper `DataType` and nothing baked is being used like eg. the `Page` content type)

Thus the actual question is: **Is there some way to enforce IntelliSense to use a certain type for the autocompletion?**

as random example, take this *XAML*:

```
<DataTemplate xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              DataType="{x:Type Accounting}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Payments}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <!--
                    Auto completion still assumes the type is Accounting
                    and displays the properties of Accounting instead of
                    the required Payments.
                -->
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Bank}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</DataTemplate>
```

And this for the *C# Classes*:

```
public class Accounting
{
    public List<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}

public class Payment
{
    public string Bank { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can use the form `{Binding Path=(xmlNameSpace:TypeName.PropertyName)}` to force a type and get completion on PropertyName.

Comment: Hi X39, any update for this issue? If Bradley's reply is helpful to resolve your issue. You could consider marking it as answer.If it persists, please check if the same issue exists after create a simple wpf project with similar structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the form `{Binding Path=(xmlNameSpace:TypeName.PropertyName)}` to force a type and get completion on PropertyName.

This causes the `Binding` to treat the path as an [attached property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview#binding-path-syntax), which falls back to a "regular" property when the attached property type is the same as the bound type.  I'm not sure if there is any additional overhead from trying to resolve it as an attached property or not, but it is enough for Visual Studio to start giving you auto-completion on the properties as you type.  I consider it a bit of a hack, as it is definitely not the intended use of this syntax,

In your specific example it would look something like (adjust for your namespace):

```
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=(local:Payment.Bank)}"/>
```

[image]

Comment: This works to some degree, i at least now get the typos properly marked as error
however, no autocompletion sadly :(

Comment: Odd, I'm getting a real autocomplete menu when I use this pattern (screenshot added).

Comment: only now getting the proper type displayed on mousehover + the underlining on typos etc.
so ... something is working

Comment: Just as a subtile note: this works up to some degree, there are some issues with this which means .. in the end one still has to remove the "abuse" of this to make it work properly sometimes. However, it does what was requested: allowing autocomplete in most cases (again, had classes where this still would not work ... cannot really tell why it sometimes did and sometimes did not work ... no common scheme)

Comment: Another late but very, very important note: the `Path=` is mandatory for this to work properly